# Master child table with foreign key and primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am designing a SQL Server database. For the following cases, which is the correct approach?

First approach:

[image: First approach using foreign key also in primary key]

Second approach:

[image: Second approach using foreign key only as unique key]

Comment: You can't have two primary keys on a table. User_Type_Id will be a foreign key on the Users table. I'm not sure what UK is supposed to be... unique key?

Comment: With the first approach you would struggle to change the user type of a given user because you would have the User_Id and User_Type_Id in any other tables that referenced the Users table. This is highly unlikely what you want. You need to be able to change a user type. So User_Id is the primary key and User_Type_Id would be a foreign key to the UserTypes table.

Comment: it all depends what your project want. Without knowing much about project, I would keep it simple by having User Id as primary key and User Type Id as Foreign Key in Users table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it if you want a user to only be part of a single user type:

```
create table UserTypes (User_Type_Id int identity(1,1) primary key
                        ,UserDescription varchar(256))

create table Users (UserId int identity (1,1) primary key
                    ,User_Type_Id int foreign key references UserTypes (User_Type_Id)
                    ,FirstName varchar(64)
                    ,LastName varchar(64)
                    ,Email varchar(256))
```

Some comments...

- This uses the `IDENTITY` property which auto increments in this example from 1 to 2+ billion
- I would split the name into first and last, so you don't have to split them later and cause headaches with name normalization
- I would avoid using reserved words like `DESCRIPTION` and `USER_ID` which are used by SQL Server and thus would need to be enclosed in brackets.

If you want a user to be part of multiple user types, then perhaps:

```
create table UserTypes (User_Type_Id int identity(1,1) primary key
                        ,UserDescription varchar(256))

create table Users (UserId int identity (1,1) not null
                    ,User_Type_Id int foreign key references UserTypes (User_Type_Id) not null
                    ,FirstName varchar(64)
                    ,LastName varchar(64)
                    ,Email varchar(256))

alter table Users 
add constraint PK_UserID_UserType PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(UserId, User_Type_Id)
```

Comment: User dose not required to be unique in the table. That is same user can be in different user types. Such as LOCAL and DOMAIN. The Combination of the User and UserType needs to be unique. By the way thank you for the answer.

Comment: Then the second part of my answer would work with a composite primary key @ArunSurendran

Comment: Thank you. Well does the Primary Key Cluster Is the correct approach or does the Unique Key is the correct approach. That was the question.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your project, I'm going to assume the first one is wrong. First, you can't have two primary keys on a table. A primary key, or a unique clustered index, organizes the physical order of the table. You can't organize it in two ways. You can PK two columns into a composite key no problem. Secondly, even if you changed the user type ID to unique instead of a PK, that means only 1 user could exist with each type ID. As soon as you tried to make another user of the same type id, you would violate that unique constraint.

The 2nd model looks better. It assumes that there cannot be the same person with the same role/user type. But the typeID in the user table should be a FK instead of a PK.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In the first approach the Users table has the composite Primary key (User_ID and User_Type_ID) where the User_Type_ID is the Foreign Key

Comment: @ArunSurendran Ok, it would be more clear if you made the PK span both fields like you did with the UK in the 2nd image. It looks like you are attempting to do 2 PK's which is not possible.